# Problemas con SDK android studio, flutter

Tags: flutter

En el LogCat me dice "Please configure Android SDK" pero tengo todo bien. Que puede ser?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que carpetas hay dentro de esa carpeta Sdk que indicas?

Comment: @diegoveloper ahi edite la publi